# Which one is the correct sentence? (Big/Bigger is not always better)

Tags: parallelism

> Big is not always better
>
> Bigger is not always better

Which sentence is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Neither sentence is incorrect (apart from the full-stop).

*Bigger is not always better* is more common (263,000 results on Google, compared to 26,800), but either would be absolutely fine to use.

Answer (score 0):

Each sentence needs to end with a period.

"Bigger" is parallel to "better", so "Bigger is better." is correct in most uses of this phrase.  "Big is better." is either an error, or has a more specific meaning such as "Big is better [than small]."

Comment: but what about this.......... i have a big house......... and someone says bigger is not always better............... but there is no comparison i did not say my house is bigger than yours

Comment: @user73052 -- When in doubt, use "Bigger is better."

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are grammatical, but they mean slightly different things.

"Bigger is not always better" means "Bigger is not always better than big." A mastiff in a New York City apartment is probably too big.

"Big is not always better" means "Big is not always better than small." Those on a diet would prefer a small portion to large one.